# Get first x items from FileInfo

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I have a `FileInfo` in C# that looks like this:

```
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("Car*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

I want to be able to select the first `x` items, let's say `30`, of the files in `files` and remove the rest from `files`. How do I do that without just looping through it from `0` to `29`?

Comment: *remove the rest from files* you want to delete them from `files` collection or from the directory(physical suppression)?

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* OP means to remove from the array named `files` since title is "get first x items"

Comment: Yeah I do mean remove from the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `GetFiles`, use [`EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_IO_EnumerationOptions_) plus [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1) and `ToArray`:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
FileInfo[] files = dir.EnumerateFiles("Car*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Take(30).ToArray();
```

This will create an array with up to the first thirty items found in the directory. This has the benefit that on really large directories it only returns thirty items *at most*. `GetFiles` will return every file in the directory *first* which can take time if there's a lot of files. `EnumerateFiles` on the otherhand, returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` which allows you to "stream" the results and apply LINQ operators *before* collecting them into an array or List.

Note: you will need to make sure that you have the appropriate `using` directive at the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Anecdotally, at one of my previous jobs, a background process would "hang" for about ten minutes and then suddenly pick up. Over time it got to taking double that time. It turned out the directory we were processing had hundreds of thousands of files in it and it was taking that long to both query the underlying win32 APIs and construct the array. Switching from `GetFiles` to `EnumerateFiles` sped the job up immensely, actually allowing it to finally catch up and process and clear all the files sitting in the folder

Comment: I would assume one could add something like `.OrderBy(o => o.FullName).Take(30)` or `.OrderByDescending(o => o.LastWriteTime).Take(30)`? Do you have any experience/idea how that would impact the performance in the anecdotal case you mentioned?

Comment: In *that* case, you'd probably have the same issue. OrderBy has to load all entries into memory first. That said, I'm fairly sure the OS returns in alphabetic order so we don't need to sort by Filename, but we *would* need to for last write.